# How to adjust photo in a frame?

Tags: android

I am making a small project in which i am trying to set a image on frame but the problem is the frames are in different forms. So may i know how may i adjust the image in these frames.

in xml...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" 
    android:background="@drawable/blank"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.9" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:src="@drawable/add" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.1" >

        <ImageView

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The code i used and the image i am able to set

```
iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            try {
                yourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Bitmap resized= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 300,300, true);


                iv1.setImageBitmap(resized);
iv1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

[image: This is the frame in which image to be set]

Update 1:
After using this code....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/blank"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:src="@drawable/add" />
    </FrameLayout>

     <LinearLayout

        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

in Activity class

```
 iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            try {
                yourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Bitmap resized= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 200,300, true);


                iv1.setImageBitmap(resized);
                iv1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }




    }
```

[image]

Comment: Add ScaleType in your xml file android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: @felix i used this code but the image is going out of the frame

Comment: Add this android:scaleType="fitXY" in ImageView  tag

Comment: Use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`.

Comment: Also must be sure that you are using weight so `width` or `height` must be `0 px` according to  `orientation` of layout.

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA i used this line and i am getting the same image as i updated above

Comment: @sophia means you have used centercrop also?

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA are you saying this Bitmap resized= Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 0,0, true);

Comment: No no i am telling at where you have used in xml file where you have used weight.

Comment: yes i used centercrop also

Comment: <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="0"
            android:layout_height="0 px"
            
            
        android:layout_weight="1" >

Comment: @sophia your frame background is fixed in your xml file or it is dynamic??

Comment: its fixed i set that in starting android:background="@drawable/blank"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51277/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-sophia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line too:

```
iv1.setImageBitmap(resized);
iv1.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

**EDIT After conversation:**

Delete `ImageView` from `FrameLayout`, We will make it dynamically in source code. Have a look on Activity source code:

```
   public class PutPhoto extends Activity
   {
    ImageView imageView3, imageView4;
    int width, height;
    FrameLayout v;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
    Bitmap yourBitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.put_photo);
        v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.ff);
        //v.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame));
        v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data)
        {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            try
            {
                yourBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(yourBitmap, 200, 300, true);
                imageView4 = new ImageView(this);
                imageView3 = new ImageView(this);
                imageView3.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.frame));
                if(imageView3.getDrawable() != null)
                {
                    width = imageView3.getDrawable().getMinimumWidth();
                    height = imageView3.getDrawable().getMinimumHeight();
                }
                Resources resources = this.getResources();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
                if (width > metrics.widthPixels)
                {
                    width = metrics.widthPixels;
                    height = width * height / imageView3.getDrawable().getMinimumWidth();
                }
                LayoutParams params=new LayoutParams(width, height);
                v.addView(imageView3, params);
                v.addView(imageView4, params);
                imageView4.setImageBitmap(resized);
                imageView4.setOnTouchListener(new Touch(PutPhoto.this));
                imageView4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView3.bringToFront();
                imageView4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Touch.java` source code for applying zoom and rotate effect on image picked up from Gallery.

```
class Touch implements OnTouchListener
{
    // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    public static float degree = 0.0f;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Context context;
    // Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix();

    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

    // We can be in one of these 3 states
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    int mode = NONE;

    // Remember some things for zooming
    PointF start = new PointF();
    PointF mid = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;

    float[] lastEvent = null;
    float d = 0f;
    float newRot = 0f;

    public Touch(Context context)
    {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
        // Dump touch event to log
        dumpEvent(event);

        // Handle touch events here...
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK)
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f)
            {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }

            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            d = rotation(event);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG)
            {
                // ...
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x, event.getY() - start.y);
            }
            else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2)
            {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    Log.v("SS", "Count=" + event.getPointerCount());
                    Log.v("SS", "newDist=" + newDist);
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    if (newDist > 10f)
                    {
                            float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                            System.out.println(newDist+" : "+oldDist+" : "+scale+" : "+mid.x+" : "+mid.y);
                            System.out.println("### Scale Value :: "+scale);
                            matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);

                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null)
                    {
                                newRot = rotation(event);
                                Log.v("Degreeeeeeeeeee", "!!!!!!!!! newRot=" + (newRot));
                                degree = Math.abs(newRot);
                                float r = newRot - d;
                                Log.v("Degreeeeeeeeeee rrrrr ", "!!!!!!!!!!! rotate :: "+r);
                                matrix.postRotate(r, v.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, v.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                    }
            }       
            break;
        }

        view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true; // indicate event was handled
    }

    /** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE", "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int action = event.getAction();
        int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
        if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
        {
            sb.append("(pid ").append(action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
            sb.append(")");
        }
        sb.append("[");
        for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++)
        {
            sb.append("#").append(i);
            sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
            sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
            sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
            if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                sb.append(";");
        }
        sb.append("]");
    }

    /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event)
    {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /** Determine the degree between the first two fingers */
    private static float rotation(MotionEvent event)
    {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        // if (Constant.TRACE) Log.d("Rotation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~",
        // delta_x+" ## "+delta_y+" ## "+radians+" ## "+Math.toDegrees(radians));
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Put your imageview in FrameLayout, add your frame as background of FrameLayout and add photo to that imageview.

Comment: the image is going out of the frame

Comment: put `android:src="@drawable/add"` in framelayout with `match_parent` layout hieght and widht both.

Comment: do i delete the image view??

Comment: NO, don't delete imageview. Just remove `src` from `imageview`.

Comment: <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rel1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:src="@drawable/add"   
            
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            
            />

i used this also still the image is going out and coming the same

Comment: try to make `imageview layout width` and `height` to `match_parent` too.

Comment: seems i have to change the whole layout

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51319/discussion-between-sophia-and-manish-dubey)

Comment: Can you provide source code with xml? i have same problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) in your layout's XML.

Comment: i used but is not solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rel1"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.9" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/add" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout

    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.1" >

    <ImageView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```